# CSOM powershell to update search navigation sharepoint 2013

Tags: search, powershell, navigation, client-object-model, global-navigation

I am wanting to write some client side powershell to update the search navigation on global search. I have found many examples of this with server side but none using client side. anyone with any ideas?

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web ServerExtensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll'

function New-SearchNavigation() 
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$siteurl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials
    )
    try
    {
##############################################################################

function AddSearchLink([string]$searchsiteUrl, [string] $navTitle,[string] $navUrl){

 $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteurl) 
 $ctx.Credentials = $credentials
$rootWeb = $ctx.Web  
$sites  = $rootWeb.Webs

$ctx.Load($rootWeb) 
$ctx.Load($sites) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery() 

foreach($searchweb in $sites) 
{ 

  $ctx.Load($searchweb) 
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery() 
    if ($searchweb.title -contains "search" ){

    Write-Host $searchweb.Title "-" $searchweb.Url  
     $node=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode -argumentlist @($navTitle,$navUrl,$true);

 $searchweb.Navigation.AddToSearchNav($node);

 $searchweb.Update()
    }
} 
 #$searchweb=Get-SPWeb $searchsiteUrl

##DeleteSearchLink -searchsiteUrl $searchsiteUrl -navTitle $navTitle

}
    AddSearchLink("mysite/search", "TEST", "/search/test.aspx")

}
    catch
    {
        Write-Host ("Error while creating search result page. Error -->> " + $_.Exception.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Output("Error while creating search result page. Error -->> " + $_.Exception.Message)
    }   
}
$credentials = Get-Credential
$url = mysite

New-SearchNavigation $url $credentials
```

I get an error saying `cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode]:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the type `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNode` and then switching `Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode` to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNode`

`SPNavigationNode` is the server object model, to use the client object model, you want `NavigationNode`.  [See here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268594(v=office.15).aspx).

However, unlike `SPNavigationNode`, `NavigationNode` does not take a constructor with two arguments, [see here for NavigationNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.navigationnode_members(v=office.15).aspx) and [here for SPNavigationNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationnode_members(v=office.15).aspx).

Comment: now says cannot find overload for navigationnode

Comment: Answer is updated.  It looks like the client model does not accept the same constructors.